# Instalação plyer não funcionou,como faze-la?

Tags: android, python-3.x, android-notification, kivy

Estou tentando fazer um app que possa enviar uma notificação ao usuário no celular dele. Para isso encontrei o pacote plyer, então usei os comandos do linux para fazer a instalação:

```
`git clone https://github.com/kivy/plyer.git`
 `cd plyer`
 `python setup.py build`
 `sudo pip install -e .`
```

e dentro do arquivo .py escrevi as seguintes linhas de comando para chamar o método para enviar:

```
`from kivy.app import App 
 from kivy.uix.screenmnager import ScreenManager, Screen
 from plyer import notification      
 class Gerenciador(ScreenManager):
      pass
 class Tela(Screen):
     def notify(self, *args):
           notification.notify(title="Notificação",message="Mensagem enviada"
 class app(App):
      def build(self):
            return Gerenciador()
 if __name__ == '__main__':
      app().run()`
```

Neste caso usei uma arquivo .kv para construir um botão dentro, e configurei um evento para quando apertar o botão ele chame o método notify() do widget raiz.
Até ai tudo bem,consigo rodar no computador dentro do ambiente virtual e tudo,porém quando passo para o celular o app nem se quer abre. Desde já agradeço pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 0):

Voce chegou a olha o arquivo ***[setup.py](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/setup.py)***?
nele tem escrito isso:

```
For Android install additional dependency PyJNIus::
    pip install https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/zipball/master
```

Não sei se resolve seu problema, mas dê uma olhada e tente instalar essa dependência.

Comment: Confesso que não olhei,mas já fiz a instalação segundo o comando que você mostrou e fui no site oficial do pyjnius e lá mostrava que poderia se colocar explicitamente o pyjnius  como um dos requerimentos. Eu fiz a instalação e coloquei nos requerimentos, mas mesmo assim não foi,  o buildozer compila, e até consigo fazer a instalação, só que na hora de abrir e executar o app isso não ocorre.